# D3 how to call functions on event when inside a class?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is an abstract of my code

```
class X {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    function1(...) {
        ...
        self = this;
        this.xyz.append('g')
            .attr("id", this.id)
            .data([{
                        "x": this.x,
                        "y": this.y
                    }
                ])
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")")
            .on("click", self.function2(this.id));
    }

    function2(...){
        ...
    }
}
```

So when the function 1 is called I've kept a listener onclick to run function2, but the function2 is never called during onclick but during first instance function1 is called. Could you please let me know my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `.on` is a function, you are instead **invoking** the function and passing it's return value to `.on`.  Further, since `this.id` is in scope of function2, I'm not sure you need to pass it.

If you do need to pass a variable, wrapper it in an anon function:

So it just becomes:

```
class X {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    function1(...) {
        ...
        self = this;

        var someValue = 6;

        this.xyz.append('g')
            .attr("id", this.id)
            .data([{
                        "x": this.x,
                        "y": this.y
                    }
                ])
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")")
            .on("click", function(){
               self.function2(someValue)
             });
    }

    function2(theValue){
        console.log(theValue); // 6
    }
}
```

**Running code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg></svg>
    <script>
    class X {

      constructor() {
      }

      function1() {
        
        var self = this,
            someValue = 6;

        d3.select('svg').append('rect')
          .attr("width", 500)
          .attr("height", 500)
          .attr("fill", "steelblue")
          .on("click", function() {
            self.function2(someValue)
          });
      }

      function2(theValue) {
        console.log(theValue); // 6
      }
    }
    
    var y = new X();
    y.function1();
    
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```